# Overriding get_context_data is blocking some context data going to the template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am inheriting from CreateView to create a form for a model.

```
class NewBlogView(CreateView):
    form_class = BlogForm
    template_name = 'blog_settings.html'
    def form_valid(self, form):
        blog_obj = form.save(commit=False)
        blog_obj.owner = self.request.user
        blog_obj.slug = slugify(blog_obj.title)
        blog_obj.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))
```

Here is my template code:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<h1>Create New User</h1>
<form action='' method='post'>{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type='submit' value='Create Account' />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

At this moment everything is working as expected, but when I am overriding `get_context_data()` my `title` field is disappearing.

```
class NewBlogView(CreateView):
    form_class = BlogForm
    template_name = 'blog_settings.html'
    def form_valid(self, form):
        blog_obj = form.save(commit=False)
        blog_obj.owner = self.request.user
        blog_obj.slug = slugify(blog_obj.title)
        blog_obj.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
       ctx = super(NewBlogView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
       print(ctx)
       return ctx
```

I am thinking although I am running the original `get_context_data()` form the function that I am inheriting, there is something that is going wrong when it comes to taking the field name from the `form_class`. Can someone help with that confusion that I have?

Comment: This code wouldn't work at all because you never return anything from your overridden method. Please post the whole thing.

Comment: `print(..)` ing an `return`ing are two *different* things.

Comment: Thanks for notifying that mistake I have made. Actually that mistake in my writing to stackoverflow, but in my code things are clean. I have fixed that